# Does those two constructions do the same thing: proces <input.txt vs cat input.txt | process in Linux

Tags: pipe, io-redirection, stdout, stdin

Does those two constructions do the same thing: `proces <input.txt` vs `cat input.txt | process` in Linux?

Comment: May I ask why I get down vote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terms you need in order to use some google-fu are 'redirection' which is what you're doing in `process < input.txt` and 'piping' which is what you're doing in `cat input.txt | process`

Once you know this, you can find articles like this one
https://askubuntu.com/questions/172982/what-is-the-difference-between-redirection-and-pipe

which answers your question nicely I think.

Comment: We generally recommend including at least a summary of any links you provide so that the answer is still relevant in case the link becomes stale (i.e. the webpage is no longer available).

Comment: Thank you, I know that one is pipe which working withs processes and another is redirection which is working with files. But I was thought about if `proces` will get the same content in both cases or if there are some differences in some special cases? In other words `process` always sees the data the same way or there any differences, should `process` do some checks to distinguish if data is read from pipe or from redirection ?